# Grub not showing boot menu after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Grub is not showing multi boot options after installing Ubuntu with windows 10.
And when looked Ubuntu was in uefi mode and windows in bios mode.It is directly booting into Ubuntu.

Comment: UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. Or once you start booting from UEFI boot menu in one mode you cannot change. And then grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode. Reinstall Windows in UEFI mode or Ubuntu in BIOS mode. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI mode since 2012 and release of Windows 8, but users still can use 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration. Or live with dual booting only from UEFI menu. How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS, is then how it installs for both Windows & Ubuntu. Windows 10 in BIOS mode is not as dual boot friendly.

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: Reinstall Windows in UEFI mode or Ubuntu in BIOS mode.